# How do I have a namespace in file?

Tags: json, node.js, nconf

This JSON within a file cannot be parsed:

```
{
  "facebook": {
    appId: "myAppId",
    appSecret: "myAppSecret"
  }
}
```

When I use this:

```
{
  "facebook:appId": "myAppId",
  "facebook:appSecret": "myAppSecret"
}
```

...the following both return null...

```
var objFb = nconf.get("facebook");

var appId = nconf.get("facebook:appId");
```

How do I add a namespace within some JSON within a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create valid JSON?

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "appId": "myAppId",
    "appSecret": "myAppSecret"
  }
}
```

Keys must be **strings**.